# android bluetooth how to disconnect without hang

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am pogramming a bluetooth device. I found when I tried to disconnect, the app will hang for some devices.

```
public class ConnectionThread extends Thread {
....
@Override
public void run() {

    bReading = true;
    while (bReading) {
        try {
            if (mInStream==null) break; 
            bytes = mInStream.read(buffer);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            cancel();
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void cancel() {
    bReading = false;
    if (mInStream != null) {
        try {
            mInStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mInStream = null;
    }
```

So I call the cancel function to stop the while loop. 
For above logic, there will be "thread dead" event, which is not good. For some device, the "thead dead" event will even cause the app hangs.

However, I dont know what wrong is the above code. I am not sure if it is caused any synchronous issue? How to improve the flow to remove the potential hang issue. any kind of advice is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the communication you can close the socket :

"

```
while (true) {
    try {
        if (mInStream==null) break; 
        bytes = mInStream.read(buffer);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        break;
    }
}
```

"

```
public void cancel(){
    try{
        mmSocket.close();
        if(DEBUG_MODE){
            Log.i(TAG, "socket closed");
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "socket close failed", e);
    }
}
```

When the socket close the loop will naturally break, since the read will fail

Comment: i just need to close the mmSocket, no need to explicit close the mInStream after read fail happen? it seems if i dont call mInStream.close(), some android phone will not release resource properly and need to restart phone to estimate the connection again. 
anyway, i dont know the most correct way to handle the disconnection event, your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: mInStream is a reference on the InputStream of the socket. If mInStream.read() fails it means the stream is closed or an IOexception occurred. In your case you close the socket which do this : "Closes the object and release any system resources it holds" if you go see the Android source you see this in the close method "mSocket.shutdownInput();" if you go further in the source you see that this method does "Closes the input stream of this socket" so you don't have to close the inputStream yourself when closing a socket =)